# How to let an Apache (Ubuntu) Proxy Server redirect/pass http to https (using VirtualHost tag in .conf file)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redirect, server, proxy

- 

Hello all,

i have set up a proxy server on ubuntu that redirects a subdomain to an ip adress (target server).

It works, but only with https.

How can i make it work in http, so that it redirects as https (the target server only works with https) ?

Here are a few (fake-)data:

- the subdomain is "mysub.mydomain.de"
- the IP of the Proxy-Server is "101.102.103.104"
- the IP of the target server is "106.107.108.109"
- the subdomain gets redirected via A-record to the proxy-server-IP

My config file under /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost mysub.mydomain.de:443>
    ServerName mysub.mydomain.de

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off    
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/Zert/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/Zert/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/Zert/intermediate.crt

    ProxyPass "/" "https://106.107.108.109:443"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://106.107.108.109:443"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost mysub.mydomain.de:80>
    ServerName mysub.mydomain.de

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off    
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/Zert/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/Zert/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/Zert/intermediate.crt

    ProxyPass "/" "https://106.107.108.109:443"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://106.107.108.109:443"
</VirtualHost>
```

What i don't understand is: even if the second VirtualHost-block redirects from port 80 to https, will it also change the port to 443 ?

Thanks!
Tim

Comment: This is confusing. There is not redirection implemented at all in that second host. There is a `ProxyPass` implemented, but that is not a redirection. I fail to see why you configure the SSLEngine here at all, you do not need the certificates, since the SSL encryption is terminated inside the proxy module anyway.

Comment: Yeah thanks, you are right. I tried to configure the http/Port80 VirtualHost the same like the first one, but actually i solved it now with this code:

{{{
<VirtualHost mysub.mydomain.de:80>
 
 ServerName mysub.mydomain.de

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysub.mydomain.de
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
}}}

Comment: That indeed is a redirection. Which does make sense.